# React Native Step Progress Bar

Tags: react-native

I need help how can I create progress bar like in the image below, I don't need code just an a idea how to create vertical lines? I already tried with react-native-svg package but I failed. Thanks

[progress bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZiov.png)

I have an array like [200, 500, 800, 1200, 2000] for example and I need to create a progress bar that will display those values and also if user have for example 250 points between 200 - 500 step I need to create those vertical lines. This progress bar I am displaying on screen like a information for that user how much points does he have and how many points he need to earn to get to the next step (500 in the example above.)

I didn't have a code, because I had no idea how to create vertical lines. But I got them work using this code

```
<Svg height={'100%'} width={width} style={styles.someStyle}>
  <Line x1="0" y1="10" x2="100%" y2="10" stroke="url(#grad)" strokeWidth="100%" strokeDasharray={`${segmentWidth} ${gapWidth}`} />
  <Line x1="0" y1="10" x2="100%" y2="10" clipPath="url(#clip)" stroke={'green'} strokeWidth="100%" strokeDasharray={`${segmentWidth} ${gapWidth}`} />
</Svg>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you please add more detail or share some code? Is it for a file downloading or a screen view loading?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting steps from the backend and between steps I need to create vertical lines dynamically based on user points like in the image.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question, this would be more appropriate as a comment. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I don't understand? I don't have code, I mentioned that I tried with react native svg to create repeatable pattern but I didn't succeed I have an array like [200, 500, 800, 1200, 2000] for example and I need to create a progress bar that will display those values and also if user have for example 250 points between 200 - 500 step I need to create those vertical lines. This progress bar I am displaying on screen like a information for that user how much points does he have and how many points he need to earn to get to the next step (500 in the example above.).